# invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char'

Tags: c

Cuando uso las funciones strcmp, strlen, strcat o strcpy me ocurre siempre el mismo error, el programa me pone lo siguiente:

> ```
> Error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char'.
> ```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?.

adjunto el codigo y una foto de un programa que estoy haciendo actualente y en el que me sale el error ya comentado.

```
voidbuscar_alumno(char dni) {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < miclase.num_alumnos; i++) {
        if(strcmp(dni, miclase.clase[i].DNI) == 0) {
            printf("\nEl primer apellido del alumno buscado es: %s", miclase.clase[i].primer_apellido);
            printf("\nEl segundo apellido del alumno buscado es: %s", miclase.clase[i].segundo_apellido);
            printf("\nEl nombre del alumno buscado es: %s", miclase.clase[i].nombre);
            printf("\nLa nota de teoria del alumno buscado es: %f", miclase.clase[i].nota_teoria);
            printf("\nLa nota de practica del alumno buscado es: %f", miclase.clase[i].nota_practica);
            printf("\nLa nota de final del alumno buscado es: %f", miclase.clase[i].nota_final);
            menu();
        }
        else {
            printf("\nNo se ha encontrado ningun alumno con el DNI introducido.");
            menu();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void buscar_alumno(char dni) {
//                 ^^^^ 

    for (i = 0; i < miclase.num_alumnos; i++) {
        if(strcmp(dni, miclase.clase[i].DNI) == 0) {
//                ^^^
```

Fíjate que, por un lado, `dni` es de tipo char, es decir, sólo puede almacenar un único caracter... y por otro estás llamando a `strcmp` que es una función para trabajar con cadenas de caracteres, es decir con variables de tipo `char*`, que son punteros.

La función debería recibir un puntero:

```
void buscar_alumno(char* dni) {
```

Aunque siendo un poco estrictos, si la variable no debería verse modificada dentro de la función lo correcto sería que la variable fuese además constante:

```
void buscar_alumno(const char* dni) {
```

Por otro lado, fíjate que tu algoritmo no sale del bucle una vez has encontrado una solución:

```
for (i = 0; i < miclase.num_alumnos; i++) {
    if(strcmp(dni, miclase.clase[i].DNI) == 0) {
        // ...
        menu();
    }
```

Esto tendrá un efecto no deseado en tu aplicación y es que después de hacer una búsqueda el programa se quedará esperando a que salgas del menú (presumiblemente usando la opción de *salir*) y entonces, en vez de abandonar el programa tu código seguirá buscando al usuario donde lo dejó. Dependiendo de cómo diseñes tu aplicación esto puede provocar casques o comportamientos inesperados.

Lo lógico es abandonar el bucle y esto lo puedes conseguir con `break` o tocando el condicional del for:

```
for (i = 0; i < miclase.num_alumnos; i++) {
    if(strcmp(dni, miclase.clase[i].DNI) == 0) {
        // ...
        // menu();
        break;
    }
```

Fíjate que la llamada a `menu()` está comentada... **no es necesaria en absoluto**. Piensa que desde `menu()` ya has hecho una llamada a esta función... cuando la ejecución abandone esta función volverá a `menu()` sin que debas preocuparte por ello.

Otro error que veo es que tu programa va a mostrar mensajes diciendo que no se encuentra el usuario aunque no sea así (y si realmente no se encuentra mostrará un mensaje por cada registro en la lista).

El mensaje de error deberías mostrarlo una vez has recorrido toda la lista, es decir, tiene que estar fuera del bucle. ¿Y cómo sabe el programa cuándo mostrar el mensaje si ya estas fuera del bucle? Puedes optar por usar variables adicionales:

```
int alumnoEncontrado = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < miclase.num_alumnos; i++) {
    if(strcmp(dni, miclase.clase[i].DNI) == 0) {
      alumnoEncontrado = 1;
      // ...
      break;
    }
}

if( alumnoEncontrado == 0 )
{
  printf("\nNo se ha encontrado ningun alumno con el DNI introducido.");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, creo que ha sido un error poner solo la funcion buscar alumno en el comentario, ya que el programa es más extenso y hay algunas cosas que comenta que tengo en el programa ya. Le tengo que hacer una pregunta, ¿podría darme algun correo o algun medio por el que contactarle y escribirle mi pregunta o creo una entadada nueva donde pongo el programa entero? Se que es abusar un poco, pero estoy preparandome para un examen en septiembre y no comprendo del todo la explicacion. Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano