# variables char en c++

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
char palabra = "HOLA";
cout<<palabra;
}
```

por que al ejecutar eso me manda el error 
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
¿Esta mal que lo haga asi?

Comment: Posiblemente esta pregunta en la misma plataforma te sirva pues creo es de lo mismo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96510/invalid-conversion-from-char-to-const-char

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> > por que al ejecutar eso me manda el error invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive] ¿Esta mal que lo haga asi?

Te da ese error porqué la variable `palabra` fue declarado como tipo `char`, esto quiere decir que la variable sólo podrá guardar un caracter.

Por ejemplo, este código no dará error de compilación:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    char letra = 'H'; //sin error.
    std::cout << letra;
    return 0;
}
```

**Solución:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    const char* palabra = "Hola"; //sin error.
    std::cout << palabra;
    return 0;
}
```

En este caso no dará error de compilación porqué el puntero `palabra` es de tipo `const char*` y la cadena literal `Hola` también es de tipo `const char*`, por lo tanto, no hay ningún error de conversión.

Ahora, **¿que pasaría si le quito el `const` al puntero `palabra`?**

Dará la siguiente advertencia si lo compilamos con [G++ de GNU](https://www.fdi.ucm.es/profesor/luis/fp/devtools/MinGW.html):

```
warning: forbids converting a string constant to char*
```

Esto ocurre porqué la cadena literal `Hola` es sólo de lectura, es decir, no lo puedes modificar en tiempo de ejecución, entonces si escribes el siguiente código:

```
char* palabra = "Hola";
```

El compilador [g++](https://www.fdi.ucm.es/profesor/luis/fp/devtools/MinGW.html) dará un warning porqué le estás dando la oportunidad al puntero `palabra` de modificar la cadena literal `Hola`. Así que por seguridad, es recomendable agregarle el `const` antes del asterisco, de ese modo, no podrás usar el puntero para desreferenciar, por ejemplo:

```
const char* palabra = "Hola";
palabra[0] = 'L'; //error
```

Dará error de compilación porqué no puedes usar el puntero `palabra` para modificar ningún elemento de la cadena.

También recalco que todo dependerá del compilador. Por ejemplo, el compilador [cl.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options?view=vs-2019) no produce ninguna advertencia y si te deja modificar la cadena literal en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Eso de _"No puedes modificar en tiempo de ejecución"_ no es del todo cierto todo depende de si acaba en una región de solo lectura o en una normal... como digo depende del compilador y del Sistema Operativo. Si realmente no pudiese ser modificado no te daría un warning sino un error

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> int main(){
>     char palabra = "HOLA";
>     cout<<palabra;
> }
> ```
>
> ¿Por qué al ejecutar eso me manda el error `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'`?

Porque un escalón no es una escalera:

---

[image]
[image]

---

Porque un eslabón no es una cadena:

[image]
[image]

---

Porque una perla no es un collar de perlas:

[image]
[image]

---

Por lo tanto un carácter `char` no es una cadena de caracteres `char *`

> `H` no es `HOLA`

---

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) una palabra entre comillas dobles (como por ejemplo `"HOLA"`) es un [literal de cadena de caracteres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/279746/2742). Los literales de cadena de caracteres tienen como tipo `const char[tamaño]` (dependiendo de cómo se escriba el literal puede ser `const wchar_t[tamaño]` u otros tipos de caracteres) es decir: formación de caracteres de tamaño `tamaño`.

Las formaciones (del tipo que sean) pueden ser transformadas implícitamente a puntero; por lo tanto una formación de tipo `const char[5]` se puede transformar implícitamente a un puntero `const char *`.

Por lo tanto, cuando escribes el siguiente código, el compilador interpreta:

```
char palabra = "HOLA";
```

1. Crea un objeto d tipo `char` con nombre `palabra`.
2. Crea una formación de tipo `const char[5]` con el contenido `'H'`, `'O'`, `'L'`, `'A'`, `'\0'`.
3. Iguala `palabra` a la formación.

   1. Dado que la formación es un valor de lado derecho, convierte a puntero.
   2. Convierte el puntero al primer elemento de la formación a `char`.
   3. ¡Error! `const char *` no es convertible a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

mejor usa el tipo de dato "string", es mejor para lo que necesitas

mal

```
int main(){
char palabra = "HOLA";
cout<<palabra;
}
```

Bien

```
int main(){
string palabra = "HOLA";
cout<<palabra;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como andas?
Las variables de tipo char almacenan un caracter.
Para almacenar un conjunto de caracteres ( string )
Podes usar

```
        `
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   string palabra = "hola";
   char * palabra2 = "Hola";
   cout << palabra << endl;
   cout << palabra2 << endl;

   return 0;
}`
```

Con cualquiera de esas dos.
Espero que te haya servido, abrazo!